# Bash script - test not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, testing

here is my simple script `prova.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "\$# = [$#]"

echo "\$1 = [$1]"

if [ $# -ge 2 || $1="-h" ]
then
echo "#########################################################################"
echo -e "usage: $0 \t launches the program only"
echo -e "       $0 -s\t shows the command fired and launches the program"
echo -e "       $0 -so\t shows only the command fired"
echo -e "       $0 -h\t shows this guide"
echo "#########################################################################"
exit 0
fi

command="ls -la"

if test "$1"="-so" || "$1"="-s"
then
        echo "Fired command:" 
        echo $command
fi


if test "$1"!="-so"
then
        $command
fi
```

here is the output:

```
$> ./prova.sh -h

$# = [1]

$1 = [-h]

./prova.sh: row 6 : [: "]" missing

./prova.sh: row6: -h=-h: command not found

Fired command:
ls -l

totale 4

-rwxrw-r--. 1 user user 632 20 lug 16.13 prova.sh
```

I expected just the help

Comment: Consider making a habit of using http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: BTW, running `$command` is inherently buggy; see [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), *I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to close every test using single brackets, the shell way, `if [ $# -ge 2 ] || [ $1 = "-h" ]; then ...` this will fix it. If you still use single brackets way, is safe to enclose you variables with double quotes, so if they are empty, you are safe, like this `if [ "$#" -ge 2 ] || [ "$1" = "-h" ]; then ...` or you can just put them inside a double bracket, and bash will handle this for you `if [[ $# -ge 2 || $1 = "-h" ]]; then ...`

Comment: `[ "$1"="-h" ]` is still wrong -- needs to be `[ "$1" = "-h" ]` _with the spaces_ to not be always true.

Comment: of course, sorry, I forgot that whitout spaces is just an assignment

Comment: inside `[`, it's not even an assignment, it's a test for whether the string `"${1}-h"` is empty (identical to `[ -n "${1}-h" ]`), and it's _always_ nonempty because it always contains the text `-h`, hence always true.